# Flask 404 not found images

Tags: python, flask

i'm working on a flask website. my project structure is
[image]

i'm loading some images using `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/devops-c.jpg') }}">`. And its loading fine when I run the server locally i.e. images are loaded fine with url
like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/devops-c.jpg`.
But when I run the same on ec2/App-service/ using code or docker container and try to access my site using public ip or dns, the images are not loading with error as

`GET http://ec2-15-217-71-73.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/static/images/background.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)`

`GET http://15.207.71.78/static/images/devops-c.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Now how can I get those images to be loaded while deployment on ec2 and access through public IP.

Comment: you have folder `Images` with upper `I` but you use `filename='images...` with lower `i` - and this makes problem on Linux servers.

Comment: File names are case-sensitive on Linux and other operating systems, but not on Windows. If you are developing on Windows the case is not a problem but deployment to a Linux server will yield this kind of "surprise".

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot `Images` is capitalized, but you try to access it in lowercase.